# Drawing a dotted background in swift

Tags: swift, core-graphics

Im trying to achieve a dotted view that I can use as a background. Something looking a bit like this:
[image: Image showing dotted background]

But I seem to be missing something in my code. I have tried to lab around with different sizes of the dots and everything, but so far I'm just getting my background color set to the view but no dots no matter the size, the color or the spacing. What am I missing?

```
class DottedBackgroundView: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    UIColor.green.setFill()
    context.fill(rect)

    let drawPattern: CGPatternDrawPatternCallback = { _, context in
        context.addArc(
            center: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 5), radius: 2.5,
            startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2.0 * .pi),
            clockwise: false)
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }

    var callbacks = CGPatternCallbacks(
        version: 0, drawPattern: drawPattern, releaseInfo: nil)

    let pattern = CGPattern(
        info: nil,
        bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10),
        matrix: .identity,
        xStep: 10,
        yStep: 10,
        tiling: .constantSpacing,
        isColored: true,
        callbacks: &callbacks)

    let patternSpace = CGColorSpace(patternBaseSpace: nil)!
    context.setFillColorSpace(patternSpace)

    var alpha: CGFloat = 1.0
    context.setFillPattern(pattern!, colorComponents: &alpha)
    context.fill(rect)

    context.addArc(
        center: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 5), radius: 5.0,
        startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2.0 * .pi),
        clockwise: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug. Just change second line to `UIColor.white.setFill()` and inside `drawPattern` change color to black: `context.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)`.

It works. I set this view on Storyboard, but if you add it from code try this:

```
let dottedView = DottedBackgroundView()
dottedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(dottedView)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    dottedView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
    dottedView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
    dottedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
    dottedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

You need to set constraints, because your custom view doesn't have defined size, therefore it's not able to resize properly.